# Create custom loss function in tensorflow with a loop

Tags: tensorflow, model, loss-function

I would like to create a custom loss function for a tensorflow model using y_true and y_pred but I got the following error:
ValueError: Cannot infer num from shape (None, 1)
this is my custom metric:

```
def custom_metric(y_true,y_pred):

    y_true = float(y_true)
    y_pred = float(y_pred)
    y_true = tf.unstack(y_true)
    y_pred = tf.unstack(y_pred)

    sqr_pred_error = K.square(y_true - y_pred)
    sqr_y_true = K.square(y_true)
    r = []
    for i in y_true:
        if sqr_pred_error[i] < sqr_y_true[i] or sqr_pred_error[i] == sqr_y_true[i]:
            result = 1
            print("result: 1")
        else:
            result = 0
            print("result: 0")
        r.append(result)
    r = tf.stack(r)

    return  K.sum(r)/K.shape(r)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need a loop in there. Looks like you just need a bunch of 0s and 1s.

- `1` - If `sqr_pred_error <= sqr_y_true`
- `0` - else

Then you can do the following.

```
def custom_metric(y_true,y_pred):

    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, 'float32')
    y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, 'float32')
    
    sqr_pred_error = K.square(y_true - y_pred)
    sqr_y_true = K.square(y_true)

    res = tf.where(sqr_pred_error<=sqr_y_true, tf.ones_like(y_true), tf.zeros_like(y_true))
    return  K.mean(res)
```

Comment: It works when I use it as a metric but as a loss I have this message error: ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0', 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0', 'dense_3/kernel:0', 'dense_3/bias:0'].

any idea ?

Comment: @JasonGreffier, well that makes sense. Because look how the tf.where operates. It's gathering a bunch of 1s and 0s that have nothing to do with the prediction itself. So there will be no gradient. I'll see if this can be salvaged to make a loss fn

Comment: Everything I tried failed, if you have success on it let me know

Comment: @JasonGreffier, yeah haven't had the chance yet. Will try to have a look today

Comment: @JasonGreffier, will something like `if sqr_pred_error <= sqr_y_true then sqr_pred_error else 0` work as a loss function? otherwise you might need to define custom gradients. I'm not even sure what you would have here as gradients though.

Comment: ok let me know if you find something. Thank you for your time !

Comment: I did not see your last comment. I will try it with if sqr_pred_error <= sqr_y_true then sqr_pred_error else 0 tomorrow.